# Join two table from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need to join table ***accounts*** and table ***users*** from my MySQL database.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM `".DB_ACCOUNTS."` WHERE `id` IS NOT NULL ";
```

table ***accounts*** and table ***users*** contain a same column as ***id***. I want to get *gender, birthday* from ***users*** and *bodybuild, weight, height, ethnictype, skincolor* from ***accounts***.

Users Table

[image]

Accounts table:

[image]

How to do this? Please help.

Comment: Please show full structure of tables `accounts` and `users`

Comment: What is the foreign key?

Comment: @SougataBose **id**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT US.gender, US.birthday,AC.bodybuild, AC.weight, AC.height, AC.ethnictype, AC.skincolor 
FROM accounts AC
INNER JOIN users US ON AC.ID=US.ID
```

You can try above code.

It will helps you.

Comment: i didnt get the the results

Comment: Could you provide sample data for same??
or create SQLFiddle demo for same.?? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT u.gender, u.birthday, a.bodybuild, a.weight, a.height, a.ethnictype, a.skincolor 
        FROM accounts a 
        LEFT JOIN users u on a.id = u.id  
        WHERE a.id IS NOT NULL ";
```

please try above query...

Answer (score 0):

Change id column in User table with userid.after that you must add userid at Accounts table as Foreign Key. userid column at Account table contain userid value from User table.

```
ALTER TABLE Accounts
ADD FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES Users(userid);

sql = "SELECT u.gender,u.birthday,ac.bodybuild, ac.weight, ac.height, ac.ethnictype, ac.skincolor
       FROM Users u
       LEFT JOIN Accounts ac
       ON u.userid=ac.userid
       WHERE ac.userid IS NOT NULL; ";
```

[image]